# I was round a long time ago

Tags: riddle

> I was round a long time ago.
>   Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.
>   I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.
>   I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.
>   Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.
>   Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.
>   In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.

What am I?

Comment: "girlfriend" seems to fit most of it if not the last line

Comment: grape seems to fit a few

Comment: @Alex If you have a girlfriend who gets smaller the older she gets, you hold on to her. XD

Comment: seems like an astronomical entity.. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm almost certain you must be a:

> Pixel

*I was round a long time ago.*

> Early display points were round, on oscilloscopes.

*Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.*

> *Without breath* refers to evacuated cathode ray tubes
>  *Around the bend* - display relies on electron deflection
>  *No longer fresh enough* - the 'refresh' rate wasn't high enough

*I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.*

> Early devices used to show many images in quick succession - new screens have an active matrix where the image persists.

*I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.*

> Each pixel actually has a red/green/blue element.

*Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.*

> As resolutions increase, pixels shrink

*Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.*

> Pixel tearing is a common issue in high-graphics gaming. EDIT: suggestion by @TwoBitOperation: Pixel tearing is due to a refresh rate mismatch; it is not the fault of the pixels themselves

*In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.*

> One dead pixel - you wouldn't throw the device.

Comment: I thought of this too, but didn't know what to make of "tear", "breath", "bend", "fresh", and "come and go". Now it makes sense. It looks like you've got it!

Comment: @deepthought: Thanks! I hope so, there was a comment by the OP about the answer relating to sitting at a computer. So I'm pretty sure it's at least on the right lines.

Comment: Was thinking along these lines, but couldn't put it all together.  This is a insightful explanation, and I think you're right.  (To add, pixel tearing is due to a refresh rate mismatch; it is not the fault of the pixels themselves)

Comment: @TwoBitOperation: I've added that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

Could it be

> a knitted sock?

*I was round a long time ago.*

> Made from a ball of wool.

*Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.*

> If socks aren't [breathable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathability), they're likely to smell bad, therefore not "fresh". ("Around the bend" could refer to the bent shape of a sock.)

*I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.*

> The sock used to be moving around a lot as you walked, but now you're sitting still at the computer.

*I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.*

> Many strands of wool were knitted together to make the sock, but it seems like a single object.

*Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.*

> The sock shrinks with age, or if put in a tumble dryer? Alternatively this could refer to the shrinking of the original ball of wool as it was used up while knitting.

*Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.*

> Knitted clothes may tear, but they don't really "rip" in the same way as cotton.

*In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.*

> You might keep a home-made knitted sock even when no longer wearing it? Alternatively, the animal who gave the wool of which the sock is knitted might be dead by now, but you still wear the sock anyway.

Comment: Oh wow, this whole time I've been misreading the title as 'I was *around* a  long time ago'!

Comment: I suppose the context of this riddle includes being at a computer. Not what I intended but we shall see perhaps you win. 

Comment: is it Compact Disc !?

Comment: @WeShall I was just thinking along those lines... magnetic tapes. I guess my idea of "long ago" is different ;-)

Comment: @deepthought: i thought of vinyl records first

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a

> Tyre

I was round a long time ago.

> It was new and filled with air.

Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.

> It got punctured and isn't as good when it was new. Without breath refers to the lack of air?

I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.

> Can't think of anything solid here. But I guess it kept losing air and you kept filling it.

I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.

> Made up many parts. It has screws, a frame, spokes etc (I'm not sure about the names of the parts)

Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.

> Some people say tyres shrink. The inner metal portion may also shrink due to cold and may flatten out due to usage.

Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.

> Nails and stones on the road may damage the tyre

In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.

> Probably you'd keep it as a spare (or stepney) tyre to be fixed later or postpone selling it as junk. So it would lie around with you for sometime.

Comment: This fits the first couple of lines *very* well, but the rest not so well.

Comment: "I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way."- ie it used to allow you to come and go? but now it can't (sorry for the vagueness, I don't know how to put spoilers in comments)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are

> a soccer ball

I was round a long time ago.

> soccer balls are nice and round when you first get them

Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.

> deflated (without breath), doesn't kick the same as it used to

I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.

> used to be played with (kicking back and forth with a friend) but now it sits there, unused

I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.

> a soccer ball has many pieces stitched together

Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.

> deflating, or getting smaller in comparison to the child who is getting bigger

Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.

> the patches tear through use, but the ball does not rip

In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.

> people tend to not throw things out, perhaps because they are a keepsake

Answer (score 4):

My guess is:

> A clementine

I was round a long time ago.

> Clementines are squished spheres, but their ancestors include the Sweet Orange, which is (almost) perfectly round.

Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.

> Like most fruits, clementines are transported to customers with careful atmosphere control (the clementine's "breath" or CO2 has to be continuously removed to prevent spoilage). Despite this, in the off season clementines usually don't taste very fresh because of how long their travel time was.

I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.

> Used to come and go refers to them not being available year-round back in the day. Now you can get them any time of year (at least for now).

I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.

> They're made up of little wedges inside, though you can't see that until you peel them

Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.

> If you leave them sitting around they slowly dry out and shrink

Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.

> I assume this refers to trying to peel the clementine with your fingers and messing it up :)

In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.

> They smell good, so some people keep them around for a long time just for the citrusy aroma.

Comment: +1; this is one of the possibilities I considered before posting [my answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/43757/5373).

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about things like wine or something Jordan.J.D had left in comment, until I saw jmb.mage's comment under rand al'thor's answer and quickly came up with *something else*.

I guess you are

> [Hard disk drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)

*I was round a long time ago.*

> This may refers to the IBM 350 disk storage, a component of [IBM 305 RAMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_305_RAMAC), the first hard drive disk being used in commercial computer for the secondary storage in 1956.
>  
>  Here's a picture of the drive:
>  
>  [image: IBM 305 RAMAC's hard disk drive]

*Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.*

> (Still *puzzled* with this line...)

*I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.*

> It supposed to be [disk packs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_pack), a removable data storage. Modern HDD [platters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_platter) are fixed inside the device.

*I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.*

> Usually a hard disk drive is composed of *more than one single platter*, yet we may think only one "disk" was installed.

*Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.*

> As we kept using the same hard disk drive, spaces available for data storage could gradually shrinking.

*Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.*

> This refers to the [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) on a HDD, which is made *nicely* through the operating system that ordered by the user, rather than done by itself.

*In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.*

> Even a HDD had crashed, we will call for data recovery - especially a broken device with some important data inside!

Answer (score 0):

You are a

> Originally: sausage...  or air, or sausage shaped air. A better fit would be an animal.

I was round a long time ago.

> Many animals are round, or bubbles are generally round.

Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.

> Around the bend sounds like a track, or field. Walking around a field could be considered going around the bend

I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.

> Old animals are less active and end up needing help to live

I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.

> This section does not fit well. Sausages are many, but animals have parts that make them a whole.

Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.

> Old shrink

Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.

> Tear and rip could be generalized, but do not fit well with all the answers.

In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.

> Dead animals could be stuffed or turned into rugs.
>  
> Is dead referring to literal or figurative death? Anything could be dead after it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Work in progress:

I think you are

> garlic

I was round a long time ago.

> garlic is fairly round

Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.

> when you eat garlic your breath stinks

I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.

> garlic can be grown year-round

I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.

> garlic clove is multiple pieces

Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.

> you use only a bit of garlic at a time?

Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.

> not sure about this

In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.

> this has something to do with vampires for sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you are

> a battery!

I was round a long time ago.

> batteries used to be round, but modern car and device batteries are rectangular

Then I was brought to you without breath and you got upset when I went around the bend saying I was no longer fresh enough.

> batteries can be "dead", and we're disappointed when they get old and lose power

I used to come and go, but now I decided to stay, or at least it seems that way.

> batteries loose charge and gain it? or

I am made up of many, but you never notice and think I am just one.

> batteries are often made of many cells [image]

Oh boy, the older I get, I keep getting smaller.

> newer model batteries are smaller than old ones?

Sometimes I tear but not rip, and it is not my fault.

> tearing outside of battery case?

In case I was dead, you'd probably keep me around anyway.

> I always save dead batteries, meaning to throw them away properly someday